# installing moviepy in python3.4 on windows

Tags: python, installation, pip

i am having problem installing moviepy on my pytho3.4 version on windows.
i wrote this code:

`py -3.4 -m pip install moviepy`

and got the error:
`File "<stdin>", line 1
   py -3.4 -m pip install moviepy`
(the pointer is on 2nd 'p' of pip)
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

tried this:
`(sudo) pip install moviepy`

got the error:
`File "<stdin>", line 1
   pip install moviepy` 
  (the pointer is on 2nd 'l' of install)
            `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

tried this:
`(sudo)pip install moviepy`

got the error:
`File "<stdin>", line 1
   (sudo)pip install moviepy`(the pointer is on 2nd 'l' of install)
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I need help installing this package...i have pip installed in my version of python i.e. Python3.4

Answer (score 1):

You are entering these commands in the Python shell. Exit it, and enter `pip install moviepy` at the regular command prompt.

Comment: i am still not able to install it. i am getting an error:      
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that  satisfy the requirement moviepy
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for moviepy
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Ruchir1123\pip\pip.log

Comment: @Ruchir then you must have some sort of network connectivity issue, or an old version of `pip`. What does the `pip.log` say?